# How to Setup and Use Tooltips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

No matter what I do, I cannot get tooltips to work.

Nothing will pop up over a link or button.

Below is an example page I'm testing with.

I want to have a glyph-halfling info-icon that when hovered over which displays a tooltip on the bottom.

Because I cannot figure out how to properly submit all my HTML page code, I am including a link to the page so you can view the source of the page and see what I have done that way.

[Example Page of tooltips not working](https://aitenterprises.com/tracker/testfile1.php)

Comment: update your question and add  a sample of your code ..

Comment: The opacity for the tooltip is set to zero. That makes it invisible on the screen.

Comment: hmmmm.. where is that set at? I dont remember setting it that way?

Comment: reset-text.less and _tooltip.scss

Comment: anyway, the tooltip for the report button works fine. Why don't you just copy that solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to include jquery first to use bootstrap tooltip functionality

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I thought i did that already though, what else must I do in order to inculde jquery?

Comment: <script src ="source to jquery"></script>

Comment: perfect! Thanks! I cant beleive I missed that... i could have swore I had included it :-)

Comment: happens, might have pasted something else over it

Comment: i have tried to replicate this over on another page, but I have ran into what could be a compatibility issue but not sure. If i use all the same jquery, and bootstrap cdn calls, it messes up my formatting, so I have only added the necessary jquery cdn call... anyways, the tooltip works but the whole page jitters and jumps up and down when hovering over the link with the tooltip. here is a link to the page https://aitenterprises.com/tracker/user_items.php

Comment: remove the styling you have given to the tooltip class.  basically remove position relative

Comment: Awesome! saved me again! Thank you!!